# Airwatch: how does it works with versions?

Tags: android, mdm, airwatch

We are supplying to one of our clients an app to be distributed by the MDM AirWatch. As far as we know, we have been using greater `versionCode` to be accepted by AirWatch.

What we are wondering is if we update from `versionCode=40` to new `versionCode=50` and something goes wrong with the app, have we send another new with `versionCode=41` or with `versionCode=51`?

In resume, does AirWatch always require a greater `versionCode` or it's ok to choose an unused `versionCode`?

To clarify, `versionName` is only used for naming reason, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, `versionCode`must increment **up** because downgrading versions is not supported. AirWatch won't accept apps with lower `versionCode`values. You still can have multiple versions of the same app in AirWatch, it is only when you add a new version that you have to choose a higher `versionCode`.

`versionName`displays in the Actual  File Version Field but `versionCode`controls the ability to version.

Reach your admin to consult the documentation from the AirWatch Online Help. Related pages:

- Using Add Version for Applications
- Uploading Internal Application

Comment: thxs for your clear explanation… As a corollary if you remove first the app from all devices, still you can't use a lower `versionCode`, right?

Comment: Never tested but it's tricky. If you delete the first and only version, then your app isn't in AirWatch any more. So, now, you have to upload it again and you could, in theory, use any `versionCode` you want.

Comment: If you have, 2 versions and delete the second one, I think the limitation is only from the first version, which is still in AirWatch. Again, never tested.

Comment: If you have 3 versions and delete the second one, your limitation will still be from the third one. You won't be able to set a new `versionCode` lower than this one.